# Where is Connection String Located as it relates to Availability Group Listeners?

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, high-availability

I am trying to teach myself about Availability Group Listeners and see that I need to update a "Connection String." I know that I have a connection string in my web.config file on the Web server, but is this where it needs to be updated? Is there somewhere in SQL Server Management Studio where it needs to be updated?

I've updated the connection string there, replacing the server name with the new Availability Group Listener Name that I've created, then updated my database table to replace the server name there with the AG Listener name too. When I update the name in the database table, my records will not open in the GUI where I'm accessing them from a website.

I think this will be a problem because if there is a failover, I'll need to manually update the name of the server for each record of the table to point to the new server location. I figured that if I put in the listener name in place of the server name, this would never need to be updated in the event of a failover.

Any thoughts? I've researched until my brain is mush and really need some help with fully understanding how to get these listeners working. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a concept of a connection string in the Availability Group. The AG is based on a Windows Cluster and a Virtual Name in the cluster that is of the type of Availability Group Listener.  This listener is configured in Management Studio in the Availability Groups container in Object Explorer.

The example that was given above is correct. SQL01 and SQL02 are actual SQL servers that are individual. They happen to be instances  of SQL on these nodes, but the nodes (or computers) participate in the Windows Cluster. When you configure Availability Groups, you specify the Instances that will participate and create a listener which becomes your server name or Data Source in your connection strings for your application.  To create the listener you have to have a Name and IP.

SQL Management Studio will not have a connection string for the AG.  You can specify the AG Listener name in your connection in Management Studio, but it would be the AG name just like your web.config or any other application file config that needs to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you. The web.config file is where I'll be updating this. I appreciate you being specific!

Answer (score 1):

If you've set-up an Always On Availability Group Listener (and you should), then you'll have a new virtual name to use in your connection string. So if your SQL Servers are SQL01 and SQL02, and there's an availability group called SQLAG01 - then you'll specify this. You could continue to specify SQL01 in your connection string, but if the Always On Availability Group has failed over to SQL02, it won't work. But if you specify the listener name, all will be well.

Make sure that you've got the latest SQL Server Native Client drivers installed so that you can use the extra settings like Multisubnetfailover and potentially ReadIntent

Comment: I have the Availability Group and Listener created. My problem is WHERE is the connection string? Is it in SQL Server Management Studio somewhere? Or somewhere else? Thank you for your response!

Comment: To clarify, I don't know how to access the connection string to edit it.